# Is it unethical to J2EE Design patterns to make another DAO call from one DAO

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, dao

Is it unethical to the spirit of J2EE Design patterns and more importantly the MVC architecture to make another DAO call from one DAO? To elaborate, should I inject another DAO class into an existing DAO class to complete my transaction?

OR

I should fetch the results of my DB output from my first DAO call-----> return to the Service Layer (BL Layer) ----------> then with the result of the first call as a parameter make the second DAO call?

Which is a better practice?

Comment: Ethics (which pertains to moral principles) has nothing to do with such design decisions - consider using different wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody is stopping you from doing it in either way. But the first approach may produce some issue like if you have more than one DML statements to be performed by two linked DAO,then if any exception thrown in the first one,may create a locked situation.
So it's always better to use service method to call another DAO if you need.

Comment: Agreed! Thanks Abhinab!

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with Arinab's answer. plus several other reason to mention  are as follows:

If you call one DAO from another then Callee DAO is tightly coupled with called DAO.

and as result of it you are not utilizing **Single Responsibility Principle**  Which is one of the core [SOLID design principle](http://www.oodesign.com/design-principles.html). this principle will help you to make **small, independent, fully functional DAO**.